# sudo mkdir /srv/www permission denied

Tags: debian, sudo, mkdir

I'm setting up a new webserver on Debian.
As my previous install had everything located in /srv/www I want to use the same setup to avoid rewriting a bunch of config files.

However executing `mkdir /srv/www` results in permission denied. Using both sudo as executing it as a su does not resolve the error.

Permissions of `/srv` are set to `drwxr-xr-x` and I'm only using a single disk that's mounted on `/`. No nfs shares.

Comment: Debian 9 (Stretch) is out of security support since 2020, and even the long-time support ended a year ago. You do *not* set up a "new" webserver on that — that's just irresponsible. To me this sounds like you're replicating some legacy system for a reason, but without knowing that reason, any answer I might give here could just counteract the actual purpose of your setup. So could you please tell us why specifically you're using debian 9 instead of a current debian?

Comment: -Can you also log in with the root user?
-Is it the same server or environment as before? (Virtualisation, hypervisor - there are differences between providers). By using `df -h`, you can see the file system and mounting point

Comment: Perhaps an attributes problem.
Try `lsattr -d /srv`.
If it shows an 'i' flag, then run `chattr -i /srv` and it should be ok.

Oh, and @MarcusMüller is right, do no use an outdated distribution !!

Comment: I'm using Debian 9 to step-wise upgrade a deployment of a webserver. Due to requirements I cannot update to the latest release directly. I am fully aware of the fact it is not secure.

Comment: lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on /srv @binarym

Comment: It's the same env as before. This is my main disk, other disks are tmpfs for /run.
`/dev/xvda1       20G  2.8G   17G  15% /`

Comment: @Daan You really need to explain these requirements. "Spend time porting something to an already outdated and insecure platform" probably isn't what is written in your job description, and helping you will require actually addressing these requirements. The `lsattr` error means you're using a strange kernel that's very much out of step to your userland software, or that your root file system isn't fit to carry attributes (unlikely). Even just with that error alone, I'd recommend upgrading to a modern debian…

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my /srv directory was mounted as ro. This could not be seen using `df -t` yet showed up using `mount`.
Remounting using the appropriate permissions solved it.